# Is there a way to see what time the phone was last placed in battery saver mode?

Tags: android, battery-saver

In my situation, I am using the Strava app on a Pixel 2 and noticed that my phone was in battery saver mode at the end of the run. I chalked that up as the reason why my usual running route was 0.2 miles off compared to the previous runs on the same app.  Is there a way to view the phone logs to know at what time I may have accidentally put the phone in battery saver mode?  I'd like to get an idea of how much of my run was performed without full GPS utilization.

I run on a twisty trail with dense tree cover and elevation changes and therefore I need full GPS functions.